# Change user group programmatically

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

i try to change the group of an user, but i won't save it. Any other data like firstname will be saved...

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(0815);
$customer->setGroupId(5);
$customer->save();
```

Comment: Not really. I want to change the group in an other event and the problem is, that the value won't get saved. Any other attribute e. g. "firstname" can be saved.

Comment: What event are you using?

Comment: It's a custom event of a custom model :/ But there's nothing after it what changes the customer data. I also tried it in a custom controller action with the code mentioned above!